# Como associar uma Checkbox a uma Lista de Objetos no Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

Seguinte pessoal, estou com uma dúvida na manipulação de uma lista de Checkboxes. Tenho uma lista de objetos que são os Cursos, e eu gostaria que essa lista estivesse vinculada à um 'List' de uma outra classe da seguinte forma:

**Encontra-se na JSP**

```
<ul><form:checkboxes element="li" path="aluno.cursos" itemValue="id" itemLabel="nome" items="${cursoList}"></form:checkboxes></ul>
```

**Classe a qual deve estar vinculada**

```
@Document(collection = "alunos")
public class Aluno {
...
private List<Curso> cursos;
...
public List<Curso> getCursos() {
    return cursos;
}

public void setCursos(List<Curso> cursos) {
    this.cursos = cursos;
}
...
```

No meu controlador a função está da seguinte forma:

```
public ModelAndView registered(@ModelAttribute("aluno") Aluno aluno, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Registrando: " + aluno.toString());
    ...
}
```

Nesse momento, eu vejo que a lista de cursos da classe aluno deveria estar setado, porém, encontra-se `NULL`
Qual a maneira correta para que eu possa vincular essa lista de Checkboxes à minha lista da classe de Aluno?

Answer (score 1):

Seu código parece correto, então o problema deve estar em outro lugar.

Provavelmente o problema é que falta implementar os métodos `equals()` e `hashCode` na classe `Curso`.

Note que quando o HTML é renderizado na tela, os checkboxes "perdem" a informação do objeto original, possuindo apenas o `id` como valor. Quando o formulário é submetido novamente ao servidor, o Spring recebe os `id`s selecionados e precisa encontrar os objetos correspondentes para então adicionar na lista final especificada no atributo `path`.